# javascript: some problem with compiler interpreting // as comments in regex 

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax, comments

I've got this regular expression for validating phone numbers

```
^(\+?|(\(\+?[0-9]{1,3}\))|)([ 0-9.//-]|\([ 0-9.//-]+\))+((x|X|((e|E)(x|X)(t|T)))([ 0-9.//-]|\([ 0-9.//-]+\)))?$
```

I dugged it out from my C#/vb library and now i want to translate it into javascript. But it has syntax error (i suspect it is something due to the // characters). my attempt:

```
$IsPhone = function (input) {
  var regex = new window.RegExp("^$|^(\+?|(\(\+?[0-9]{1,3}\))|)([ 0-9.//-]|\([ 0-9.//-]+\))+((x|X|((e|E)(x|X)(t|T)))([ 0-9.//-]|\([ 0-9.//-]+\)))?$", "");
  return regex.test(input.trim());

};
alert($IsPhone("asd"));
```

Comment: Can you please give some context about what your expression is attempting to match?  It will make it easier to debug.

Comment: Have you tried to escape the slashes?

Comment: what is this? a game of "spot the difference"? Anyway, if it is a syntax error I would try using JSLint.

Comment: Why would you need to double the slashes anyway? AFAICS, they're in a character class, so a single one should do.

Comment: My guess is you wanted to write `[ 0-9./-]` instead of `[ 0-9.//-]` (putting it twice doesn't make any sense, and might cause the regex to be flawed)

Comment: @maple_shaft heys i've updated my question

Comment: @SJuan76 heys i've updated my question

Comment: @Ingo heys i've updated my question

Comment: @krookedking heys i've updated my question

Comment: Care to explain what "it's not working" means exactly. One error is that your regex starts with ^$ which on itself would match an empty string, but in your regex is then followed by something. Care to explain the intended meaning of that?

Comment: @Ingo its not working because there's a syntax error with it. i suspect it is due to the // in the regex string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [Errors translating regex from .NET to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055585/errors-translating-regex-from-net-to-javascript)

> The backslash character in JavaScript
>   strings is an escape character, so the
>   backslashes you have in your string
>   are escaping the next character for
>   the string, not for the regular
>   expression. So right near the
>   beginning, in your "^(+?, the
>   backslash there just escapes the + for
>   the string (which it doesn't need),
>   and what the regexp sees is just a raw
>   + with nothing to repeat. Hence the error.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem has nothing to do with comments.  You're just mixing up the two different ways of creating RegExp objects.

When you create a RegExp object in JavaScript code, you either write it as a string literal which you pass to a RegExp constructor, or as a regex literal.  Because string literals support backslash-escape sequences like `\n` and `\"`, any actual backslash in the string has to be escaped, too.  So, whenever you need to escape a regex metacharacter like `(` or `+`, you have to use *two* backslashes, like so:

```
var r0 = "^$|^(\\+?|(\\(\\+?[0-9]{1,3}\\))|)([ 0-9./-]|\\([ 0-9./-]+\\))+((x|X|((e|E)(x|X)(t|T)))([ 0-9./-]|\\([ 0-9./-]+\\)))?$";
var regex0 = new RegExp(r0, "");
```

The forward-slash has no special meaning, either to regexes or strings.  The only reason you ever have to escape forward-slashes is because they're used as the delimiter for *regex literals*.  You use backslashes to escape the forward-slashes just like you do with regex metacharacters like `\(` or `\+`, or the backslash itself: `\\`.  Here's the regex-literal version of your regex:

```
var regex1 = /^$|^(\+?|(\(\+?[0-9]{1,3}\))|)([ 0-9.\/-]|\([ 0-9.\/-]+\))+((x|X|((e|E)(x|X)(t|T)))([ 0-9.\/-]|\([ 0-9.\/-]+\)))?$/;
```