# Errors translating regex from .NET to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, web-services

I have this piece of VBNet code that i would like to translate into javascript:

```
  Dim phone_check_pattern = "^(\+?|(\(\+?[0-9]{1,3}\))|)([ 0-9.//-]|\([ 0-9.//-]+\))+((x|X|((e|E)(x|X)(t|T)))([ 0-9.//-]|\([ 0-9.//-]+\)))?$"
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("test input", phone_check_pattern))
```

my translated result:

```
var phone_check_pattern = "^(\+?|(\(\+?[0-9]{1,3}\))|)([ 0-9.//-]|\([ 0-9.//-]+\))+((x|X|((e|E)(x|X)(t|T)))([ 0-9.//-]|\([ 0-9.//-]+\)))?$";
alert(new RegExp(phone_check_pattern).test("test input"))
```

However when i run it it has error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:: Nothing to repeat`

(my VbNet code doesn't have any error though)

Does anyone know what's causing the problem?

Comment: @Pacerier Can you tell us what the regEx is supposed to do.

Comment: @sra: He's taking on the formidable (some would even say Quixotic) task of validating a phone number entered in a free-form field. Not for the faint of heart, and prone to all sorts of problems.

Comment: @sra its stated in the question, within the code

Comment: @Pacerier Oh, yes. I should read more closely next :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The backslash character in JavaScript strings is an escape character, so the backslashes you have in your string are escaping the next character *for the string*, not for the regular expression. So right near the beginning, in your `"^(\+?`, the backslash there just escapes the `+` *for the string* (which it doesn't need), and what the regexp sees is just a raw `+` with nothing to repeat. Hence the error.

Fortunately, JavaScript has a literal syntax for regular expressions (delimited with `/` characters), which would probably be a better starting point for you:

```
var re = /^(\+?|(\(\+?[0-9]{1,3}\))|)([ 0-9.\/-]|\([ 0-9.\/-]+\))+((x|X|((e|E)(x|X)(t|T)))([ 0-9.\/-]|\([ 0-9.\/-]+\)))?$/;
alert(re.test("test input"));
```

Then at least the backslashes are escaping in the regex, not the string. (Note that since `/` is the delimiter for the regular expression literal, we have to escape it (with a backslash).)

I haven't exhaustively reviewed the actual regexp, but that should get you started.

More about regular expression literals in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), of course, and [here on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but try to use `\\` instead of `\` in your javascript code. Seen some samples that did this.

Answer (score 1):

The double-slash, as everyone said, is important. This works:

```
var phone_check_pattern = "^(\\+?|(\\(\\+?[0-9]{1,3}\\))|)"+
    "([ 0-9.//-]|\\([ 0-9.//-]+\\))+"+
    "((x|X|((e|E)(x|X)(t|T)))([ 0-9.//-]|\\([ 0-9.//-]+\\)))?$";

var re = new RegExp(phone_check_pattern);
say(re.test("test input"));
say(re.test("(415) 828-3321"));
say(re.test("+1 (212) 828-3321"));
say(re.test("da828-3321"));
```